# Is Z7 (integer modulo under addition) a vector space over Z5??

Tags: vector-spaces

It satisfies internal and external composition conditions. (Z7,+) is an abelian group as well. I cant find a reason why it should not be a vector space. Can you please help me with how to prove it is not a vector space??

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If this is a vector space over $\mathbb Z _5$, then 
$$ 5=5 \cdot 1 =0\cdot 1 \pmod{7}$$

Comment: I get that you are assuming 5 to be from Field *Z5* and leading to a contradiction. But I don't understand whether we can make the assumption in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $V$ is a finitely generated vector space over the finite field $F$, then
$$
|V|=|F|^{\dim_F V}
$$
(use a basis).

---

About your “solution”: how would you define the external composition?

Comment: V=Z7={0,1,2,3,4,5,6} and F= {0,1,2,3,4}. Taking 4 from F and say 2 from V, 4*2 (mod7) does belong to V. Is anything wrong with this reasoning?

Comment: @VarunYadav Can you verify the vector space axioms?

Comment: Since multiplication by the scalar identity needs to be trivial, there is actually only one way of defining the scalar multiplication ;)

Comment: I just can't understand how to go on to define scalar multiplication in this case: whether c*v should be equal to c*v(mod 5) or c*v (mod7) or something else. Because if we take the second case, the scalar product does belong to Z7. Also how the multiplication with unity of Z5 is to be conceived in such a case?

Comment: @VarunYadav Indeed, you *cannot* define a scalar multiplication in this case!

Comment: @VarunYadav did you figure a solution for this?

Comment: @egreg we know that if F is a subfield of V then V is a vector space over F. However I see some solutions taking this the wrong and say that since Z5 is not the subfield of Z7 and concluding Z7 is not a vector space. Are those solutions correct? Can you help me understand?

Answer (score -1):

$\mathbb Z _5$=${(0,1,2,3,4})$ If we pick $2,3$ from $\mathbb Z _5$ then $(2+3=0\mod 5)$  is in $\mathbb Z _5$ but $(2+3\neq0\mod 7)$ in  $\mathbb Z _7$ ,so inverse of $2$ in $\mathbb Z _5$ is different in $\mathbb Z _7$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).